# How can I deploy an asp mvc app to a different computer using IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment

Is there a way to deploy my mvc web app to another computer (which will be used as a server).

Also, in the server, there is no Visual Studio installed, how can I deploy it there?

Answer (score 0):

Check out those links below:

[Access from another PC](https://forums.asp.net/t/1756634.aspx?How%20to%20access%20IIS%20hosted%20site%20from%20another%20PC)

[Run project on another PC](https://forums.asp.net/t/2033718.aspx?How%20to%20run%20my%20asp%20net%20web%20application%20on%20another%20computer%20in%20the%20same%20network)